# Hold php variable for an hour then execute condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I got a simple form to send emails, now im facing an issue, im getting variables from 2 differents pages send to the same php page to submit the email. both variables are sent via ajax. 1 section is an array and the other its a confirmation variable, page  A that has array emails to waiting.php page and page B sends 1 value as well to waiting.php .

```
 <?php
$groupD = "yesy";//$_GET["info"];

  //sleep (60);
   foreach ($groupD  as $gtm) {
   $message .= $gtm;
  $test .=  $mail[9];
  echo $test;

    }
 $groupx = $test;   
 $groupz = "someting ";  //$_GET["confirm"];
 $datetime1 = new DateTime($test ); 
$datetime2 = new DateTime();
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
//echo $interval->format('%h');

if ($interval->format('%h') > 1 ) {
if (!is_null($groupx) & !is_null($groupz)){
/// mail function

  }
else{
    echo "false empty fields";
}
}
else{
    echo "time false";
}


 ?>
```

will it even work if i use sleep class from php. page A has the submit time its fetch out from the array so i can use it with interval, my question will be, should i keep both variables on hold and after an hour , release or which is the best approach, will highly appriciate you guys help.

here is my js

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready( function() {
  var msg = google_tag_manager["GTM-xxx"].dataLayer.get('hPackageId');
  var msg1 = google_tag_manager["GTM-xxx"].dataLayer.get('hPackageTotal');  
  var msg2 = google_tag_manager["GTM-xxx"].dataLayer.get('hUserName');
  var msg3 = google_tag_manager["GTM-xxxx"].dataLayer.get('hUserLastName');
  new Date(Date.parse).toUTCString()
  var d = new Date();
   d.setTime(d);
   var msg4 =(d.toString().slice(0, 24));
   var getall = [msg, msg1, msg2, msg3, msg4];
  // console.log(getall);

   $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
    url: "mypagepage.php",
    data:{info: getall},
     datatype: 'html',
    success: function(data) {}
   });

  });

 </script>
```

both scripts are sent via ajax due my scenario, page A page B has the same sintac

Comment: Regular variables in one script are not visible in another script. Set a session variable in the first script, then use it in the second script.

Comment: i edited my post so you can see my js scritp

Comment: JS code is mostly irrelevant, this is being done in PHP.

Comment: im using gtm to create tags and triggers,the  script is since i dont have access to the back-end, page must not reload on submit and variables are fetch from data layer

Comment: You can't send mail from front end, can only be done on back end.

Comment: all info is sent to a php page created which i got access to via ftp, but i do not have access to database or any other access, all i can do is front, mail function can be send via js as well

Comment: You need something to execute at a time when the user hasn't sent a request, an hour after the last AJAX request? That's hard to do without a DB and cron access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scripting languages such as PHP are generally designed to respond to an individual web (e.g., https) request and do something **right away**. I have used sleep() in PHP scripts when they are running in the background, but that is a different type of setup. Putting a delay in a regular script **might** work, but will result in extra processes running - e.g., if 100 people use the page in an hour then there will be 100 processes running at the same time. While most of the processes would be sleeping (not wasting CPU cycles) that is still a significant load on the server in terms of memory, process descriptors, etc.

If I understand the question correctly, you want to process multiple parts of a transaction that results in an email being sent after an hour of wait time for completion or changes. I suggest using a database (e.g., MySQL) to store the information from each request. Have a separate process - e.g., a cronjob run automatically once an hour - read information for all unsent emails from the database, send the emails and update the database so that the emails won't get sent again an hour later.

Comment: you understood correctly, basically the info si coming from 2 different pages  page A is submitted right way page B delays up to 1 hour max, when i have both variables is when i will subit based on the info. i only have access to front-end dev no access to data bases

Comment: @walteralexander Doing this properly requires some sort of storage. If you can't use a MySQL instance then use a local (but NOT temporary) file. You can have one big file of all pending transactions or one for each transaction. Add one more process that runs as a cronjob or, as a poor man's cronjob, add a test at the end of another process (so it doesn't delay user displays) - essentially "check for file with pending transactions and process any that are more than an hour old and haven't been processed yet" - with NO visible output (i.e., just file updates and emails). Crude but I've done it.

Comment: thnks i will give it a try